# DataTriggers based on column name and its value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` that is generating automatically its columns with a `DataTable` in code.
I need to change a background color of a row if column X have value of `FALSE` or whatever.
Can I do it with `AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"` eventargs?
If not how can I change the Style of a row using, maybe, `DataTriggers` accessing the column value and affect background color of the row?

EDIT 1:
Straight forward question: How can I change background color of a row based on a value on some column?

EDIT 2:
Based on Generating Columns Event I can do this:

EDIT 3: coding

```
public static void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            try {

                if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime) && e.Column.Header.ToString() != "Data de Registo")
                    (e.Column as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

                if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime) && e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Data de Registo")
                    (e.Column as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
                if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "FT")
                {
                    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("<Style xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\""
                        + " TargetType=\"{x:Type DataGridCell}\">"
                        + " <Setter Property=\"Background\" Value=\"Red\"/>"
                        + " </Style>");
                    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
                    Style style = (Style)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
                    e.Column.CellStyle = style;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

So I changed background color of a column (its cells) but what I want is checking its value for each row and make it red if value X or green if value Y.

Comment: sorry removed it ... that was not planned to be here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Style` and `DataTrigger` for the `DataGrid`. Then format according to the bound data item.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=<!--Your property name here-->}" 
                         Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="<!-- Your desired Brush here-->" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

If you want to access the default indexer property of the bound data item, make your path `Path=[IndexerName]` or `Path=[(sys:Int32)0]`.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you!
Everytime I use "binding path" I'm referring to the object that datagrid refers to right?

Comment: When you set the style to the `DataGridRow` (hence `DataGrid.RowStyle`) it will use the `DataContext` of that row. The `DataContext` of that row is by the `DataGrid` logic actually the bound `Row[i]` of your `DataTable`.